# Change dropdown button colour on click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have a drop down menu like this:

```
<div class="sub-page-container">
    <div class="indented-box">
        <form class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h4>Button Label</h4>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" id="position-type">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" id="position-type">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> Other <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></span> Option A
                                    </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></span> Option B
                                    </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

First let me apologise for the number of indentations. I know it's excessive, but it is necessary. Anyway, for explanation: `sub-page-conainer`and `indented-box` are my own classes and define no button-related content; of this I am confident. The reason this button group is nested inside another is that there are other buttons as well but they would only complicate an already complicated setup so I excluded them.

And I want to set button's `background-color` property when the menu is opened. Is it possible to do this in CSS, and if so, how would I do it?

Comment: Have you checked the bootstrap docs to see if there's a hook or something? Doesn't the class change when opened?

Comment: I checked but was unable to find anything that didn't require javascript. I figured, since you could do this with regular buttons, you should be able to do it with drop-downs as well but maybe I'm mistaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use dropdowns you already do use jQuery, don't you?

Anyhow, when you take a look at the [example on getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) you can see (inspect dom) that at least two things change on toggle.

1. The button's attribute `aria-expanded` changes from true to false (and back).
2. The parent div's class is modified and the class `open` is added.

You can use either of these to target your button when dropdown is visible.

## Solutions

1. button.btn[aria-expanded="true"] { background: red; }
2. .btn-group.open button.btn { background: red; }

Maybe you need to be more *specific* or add `!important` for your rules to be applied over the defaults.

Comment: Thanks. I read their javascript documentation on dropdowns but I'm still new to this web development thing. So, I really appreciate your helpful hints. At any rate, it turns out that bootstrap was setting the property somewhere and I overriding it required `!important`. Was hoping not to use that, it seems like a really nasty habit to get into, but there wasn't any helping it

Comment: You can probably work around `!important` by being more *specific* than bootstrap. I don't know how your html looks but something more complex like `body > div + div.someClass article button.btn[aria-expanded="true"]` might work. If you update your question with some more of your html I might find something.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. If I could impose further, I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change it only with css you could add the **tab-index="1"** to your button and use **button:focus** in css. Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/abmvpzve/).

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tab-index="1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> Other <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></span> Option A
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></span> Option B
     </a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
button:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

However you might want to check the bootstrap documentation and/or also try to achieve this with jQuery/javascript.

**EDIT**

Ooops... I mean **tabindex** not **tab-index** and it actually should work without that attribute as well as the button tag is of type input so you can have focus on it by default.

Comment: It's close. Without your implementation, when clicked the button only darkens slightly in the normal fashion. However, with your implementation, it changes to the chosen colour after the drop-down list is closed for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with jQuery

```
$( function() {
  $('button.btn-default').click( function() {
    $(this).css('background', '#aaa')
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Would prefer to do it without jQuery if possible. If I have to use javascript fine, but I don't want to add another library if possible

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("btnBackground");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jpf9qb14/)

Comment: This looks like a jQuery implementation to me